# Roots of unity and probability

Tags: probability

Let v and w be randomly chosen distinct real or imaginary roots of equation $x^9-1=0$. Find the probability that |v+w| greater than or equal to 1. 
I am getting answer as 3/4. 
My method: sample space is 36.
Now for given condition i got that arg(v/w) should be less than or equal to $2\pi/3$. So i got favorable selections as 27.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: By symmetry, we may assume $v = 1$.  Six of the other $8$ roots qualify, so $3/4$ is correct.

Comment: Yes . Thankx for the help.